# Every positive power of $5$ appears in the last digits of bigger power of $5$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Problem. Show that for every positive integer $n$, there is an integer $N > n$ such that the number $5^n$ appears as the last few digits $5^N$. For example, if $n = 3$, we have $5^3 = 125$ and $5^5 = 3125$, so $N = 5$ would satisfy.

This is a problem from the worksheet of the class Putnam Seminar at CMU. Please give hints towards the right direction and not the full solutions. Thanks!!

Comment: Why is the `contest-math` tag used? Please [edit] the question to add that context.

Comment: @Shaun Well what I'm I suppose to add? It was a problem on the worksheet from my Putnam class. It feel like saying that is just distracting

Comment: Well, the fact that it's from your Putnam class. Don't worry about potential distractions. Context is strongly encouraged by many users here and, typically, it can be very helpful for some users for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix $n$.
The cases $n \le 3$ can be handled directly.
We now assume $n > 3$.

Let $m = \lceil n \log_{10} 5 \rceil$ be the smallest integer such that $10^m > 5^n$. For $n > 3$, we have $m < n$.

You want to find $N$ such that $5^N = k 10^m + 5^n$ for some integer $k$. Dividing both sides by $5^n$ yields $$5^{N-n}  - 1 = k 2^m/ 5^{n-m}.$$

Thus if you show you can find a large integer $q$ such that $5^q - 1$ is divisible by $2^m$ then you can choose $N$ and $k$ appropriately to conclude the proof.

---

> Base case: For $m=2$ we have $5^1 - 1$ divisible by $2^m$. Inductive step: if $5^q-1$ is divisible by $2^m$, then $5^{2q}-1 = (5^q-1)(5^q+1)$ is divisible by $2^{m+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We will prove that there exists a $N$ such that $5^n$ and $5^N$ have the same last $n$ digits

So what we need to do is to find $5^N\equiv 5^n\pmod{10^n}$

This can be achieved by setting $N=n+\phi (2^n)$

Since $5^N\equiv 5^n\pmod{5^n}$ and $5^N\equiv 5^n\pmod{2^n}$

Comment: Could you explain to me how you reached the last two lines?